# What should I do about an internal error when I declare a generic "array of T"?

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe2

This unit fails to compile in XE2 Update 3 with "[DCC Fatal Error] Test.pas(22): F2084 Internal Error: URW1147"

```
unit Test;

interface

type
  TSorter<T> = procedure(var Values: array of T);

  TTest = class
  public
    procedure Sort<T>(const Sorter: TSorter<T>);
  end;

implementation

procedure TTest.Sort<T>(const Sorter: TSorter<T>);
begin
end;

end.
```

I have submitted a QC report: [QC#103671](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=103671).

Does anyone have an idea about workaround for this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you replace TSorter declaration with `TSorter<T> = procedure(var Values: TArray<T>);` it compiles fine on XE.